# Relationship between ContentDistribution and ContentDocument build SOQL query

Tags: soql, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdistribution

Is there a way to query ContentDistribution and ContentDocument ?
I'm looking to pull few fields from ContentDocument while building the ContentDistribution query.

Here is what I have done so far:

> SELECT Id,Name,ContentVersionId, ContentVersion.FileType,
> ContentVersion.Title, ContentVersion.FileExtension,ContentDocument.Id
> FROM ContentDistribution

the above query throws an error due to ContentDocument.Id

> Didn't understand relationship 'ContentDocument' in field path

Comment: Can you go through the ContentVersion?  e.g. `ContentVersion.ContentDocument.Title`

Comment: yes I have thought about going through ContentVersion.ContentDocument.Title but how would I get the fields from ContentDistribution associated with ContentVersion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `ContentDistribution.ContentDocumentId` references a `ContentDocument`, there is no `relationshipName` to traverse. You can see this via Workbench, contrasting `ContentDocumentId` versus `ContentVersionId`.

Since `ContentVersion`'s parent is `ContentDocument`, you can get `ContentDocument` fields as as a grandparent of `ContentDistribution` follows:

```
SELECT Id,Name,ContentVersionId, 
       ContentVersion.ContentDocument.ContentSize, // a field on ContentDocument
       ContentVersion.FileType, ContentVersion.Title, 
       ContentVersion.FileExtension,ContentDocumentId
FROM ContentDistribution
```

[image]

Comment: Can a query be written FROM ContentVersion that includes fields from contentDistribution? For example:
 
select id, description, title,
contentDocument.fileType,
(Select name from contentDistributions),
contentDistribution.DistributionPublicUrl
 from contentversion

Comment: @SeanW - your suggestion does not work as there is no relationship name from `ContentVersion` to `ContentDistribution`